# Holding left mouse to loop sound file

Tags: game-engine

For a shooting game, I need to make it so when the left mouse button is held down a sound file repeats. If it can be done just using the logic editor that would be good, but use of python would be fine.
I don't think it's necessary to supply the .blend file, but if you need it then ask.

Comment: I worked out how to do it now. You just have to attack a left mouse sensor to an and controller then loop end the sound file.